# SonarQube 4.x only with embedded Tomcat -> could you add AJP suppor for proxy with Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat, sonarqube, ajp

I understood that SonarQube only support embedded mode with versions 4.x. I need to run the server behind an apache Server. Therefore I need the AJP support for the embedded Tomcat server.

Could you document how to enable the AJP support on Tomcat side and how to configure the port number. To my knowledge it is the only reliable way to run a tomcat application behind Apache server over https.

The variant of configuration my own SSL certificate into the embedded tomcat has a few drawbacks

- I have currently more than 12 servers running behing Apache and do not really want to configure 12 times servers.
- I want to run all servers through the standard https ports to simplify the URL
- I prefer to avoid setting up 12 Ubuntu server instances and being 12 SSL certificates (or a wild card certificate).

*[Above remarks added to clarify the comments]*

Thanks

Marcel Baumann

Comment: Hello, could you tell us what have you tried or what are your ideas? I don't think that "please do that for me" questions are appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: I am running about 12 servers behind an apache server with official certificate and only allowing https. Literature seems to show that only the configuration     <Location /sonar>
        ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/sonar
        ProxyPassReverse https://<myhost address>/sonar
</Location>   The variants using directly https do not work because sonarcube makes a redirect during login. If you have an apache 2.x configuration supporting redirection of https traffic without the ajp protocol i am very iterested. Could not find any working example on apache.org or in blogs

Answer (score 1):

It is not yet supported. Feel free to follow and vote for http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4742

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you have to add this modules in apache: rewrite, proxy and proxy_ajp

And add this configuration site to your apache (change localhost if your sonar/tomcat is in another server)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sonar.yourdomain.com
    ServerAlias sonar
    ServerAdmin your@email.com

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/sonar/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/sonar/access.log combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sonar/

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/$ /sonar/ [R]
    RewriteRule ^/sonar$ /sonar/ [R]

    ProxyPass /sonar/ ajp://localhost:8009/sonar/
    ProxyPassReverse /sonar/ ajp://localhost:8009/sonar/
</VirtualHost>
```

If you want to use SSL just change the port 80 to 443 and add module: ssl     and include certificatekeyfile configuration of your ssl certificate,

Hope it helps ;)